# Log success/failure metric for a asynchronous job on Amazon Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

Here is a brief description of what I am trying to achieve.

`Application details:`

We owned an API (StartJob) that kicks off an asynchronous job of an application (not owned by us) and returns a `unique id` which is later used to retrieve the status of the job.

Then we have another API(GetStatus) which internally calls the application to retrieve the status (i.e. Successful/failed/running) and return to the user.

`Goal:`

Our goal is log # jobs were started, failed, and successful on  Amazon cloud-watch.
Logging # jobs started is in `StartJob API`. But logging success/failure metric is not straightforward as multiple calls to `GetStatus API` for the same success/failed job would log twice hence destroying the metrics.

Does cloud-watch provide something like for a unique id metric that is not logged twice?

Thanks